# Можно ли хранить указатели на другие таблицы в одном из столбцов таблицы?

Tags: sql, postgresql, nosql

У меня имеется не сложная графовая модель данных, но я хотел бы попробовать хранить ее в обычной SQL базе данных, для этого мне нужно для каждого поля одной таблицы иметь указатель на соответствующую таблицу, можно ли это сделать в postgresql?

Как я понимаю, просто указать имя новой таблицы будет не эффективно с точки зрения поиска этой таблицы среди миллиона подобных.

Comment: Можно, но не нужно. Используйте либо sparse table - для ссылки на каждую таблицу своё поле,- либо EAV. А если таблицы содержат однородные данные - их следует объединить и добавить идентифицирующее поле.

Comment: @Akina, но ведь таблицы содержащие личные сообщения не обьединить, это очень неправильно, так как может привести к утечке данных по идее

Comment: PostgreSQL распрекрасно себе поддерживает ROW LEVEL SECURITY. И если не заниматься такой дурью как "все юзеры под одной учёткой", то никаких проблем с безопасностью и утечек, по крайней мере с этой стороны, не может быть.